# wordpress - swf and fullscreen in flash =>11

Tags: wordpress, flash

yesterday , a friend has called me and told me that his website is not working well - 
the problem is that the "fullscreen" mode is not working on any computer where flash player was updated to 11.0 and above .

It is working fine on my computer (because I always refused updates and working with 10.4) but when I looked at his code , it seems that everything is fine .
However - it is true that when flash player => 11.0 is installed - the fullscreen mode is not working ..
What can be the problem ?

How can it be solved ?
(He is using a simple plugin called [swf object](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/swfobj/download/) to generate the necessary javascript - and when I looked at the code , it looks fine ...)

```
<object width="760" height="300" name="flv-1" allowfullscreen="true" data="http://www.began-haem.com/ganhaem/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/began-haem-1-1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

and

```
<param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
<param value="flv-1" name="name">
```

Normally those two things should do the trick ...

I am lost here - does anyone has a clue ?
Did something substantial was changed between the flash player 10.x and 11.x ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that it is not a script error -

after hours of fighting and searching and modding , I found that it is a **BUG** in the latest version of flash player. (11.3.300.271  and 11.4.402.265 depending on your browser..)

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3310959